# Xamarin Dependent Binding

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms

I'm struggling to figure out something that I feel should be very basic and I hope someone can help me.

I'm trying to make a custom control visible depending on whether or not data has been provided to it.

For example:
I have a main page that uses a custom control as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:XamarinDependantProperty.Controls;assembly=XamarinDependantProperty"
             x:Class="XamarinDependantProperty.Pages.MainPage">
    <ContentPage.Padding>
        <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="Thickness">
            <On Platform="iOS" Value="0,20,0,0"/>
        </OnPlatform>
    </ContentPage.Padding>
    <StackLayout>
        <Label Text="Welcome to Xamarin Forms!" VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="Center" />
        <controls:CustomEntry TextValue="Test" VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="Center"></controls:CustomEntry>
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

The custom control looks as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ContentView xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="XamarinDependantProperty.Controls.CustomEntry" IsVisible="{Binding TextIsVisible}">
    <StackLayout>
        <Label Text="{Binding TextIsVisible}"  />
        <Label Text="{Binding TextValue}"  />
    </StackLayout>
</ContentView>
```

And the code behind is as follows:

```
using System;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Xaml;

namespace XamarinDependantProperty.Controls
{
    [XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
    public partial class CustomEntry : ContentView
    {
        public CustomEntry()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            BindingContext = this;
        }

        public string TextValue
        {
            get { return (string)GetValue(TextValueProperty); }
            set { SetValue(TextValueProperty, value); }
        }

        public static BindableProperty TextValueProperty = BindableProperty.Create(nameof(TextValue), typeof(string), typeof(CustomEntry));

        public bool TextIsVisible => !String.IsNullOrEmpty(TextValue);
    }
}
```

If I set the CustomEntry's TextValue to "Test" the the output is:

> Welcome to Xamarin Forms!
>
> False
>
> Test

If I put in an empty string, then there is no output at all, the application starts but nothing is displayed.

If I set the default value of the TextValueProperty to null then the output is:

> Welcome to Xamarin Forms!

From the outputs it appears that when I set the TextValue, the TextIsVisible value is working in the first binding (IsVisible) even though the second binding (Text) outputs False, but why is it false?

If I don't provide a value and I don't tell it that null is an acceptable empty value then it screws up completely but it doesn't say anything to that regard. No error, not output, nothing. Is there a way to see that something went wrong? (testing on a iphone simulator)

And then if I take this concept out of this test situation and put it into a real situation. Then setting TextValue and outputting TextIsVisible is still false but it isn't displaying.

What am I doing wrong? What am I not understanding?

Comment: You need to raise `NotificationChanged` for `TextIsVisible` on the TextValue `setter`.

Comment: @JesusAngulo Could you elaborate on that please?

Comment: I've updated my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to raise the **propertychanged** event for `TextIsVisible` to notify the View that this **property has changed**.

```
[XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
public partial class CustomEntry : ContentView
{
    public CustomEntry()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        BindingContext = this;
    }

    public string TextValue
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(TextValueProperty); }
        set{SetValue(TextValueProperty, value);OnPropertyChanged(nameof(TextIsVisible));}
    }

    public static BindableProperty TextValueProperty = BindableProperty.Create(nameof(TextValue), typeof(string), typeof(CustomEntry),propertyChanged:OnTextChanged);

    private static void OnTextChanged(BindableObject bindable, object oldvalue, object newvalue)
    {
        var entry = bindable as CustomEntry;
        entry?.OnPropertyChanged(nameof(TextIsVisible));
    }

    public bool TextIsVisible => !String.IsNullOrEmpty(TextValue);
}
```

Comment: It's a shame that the OnTextChanged part is necessary.
I feel like there must be a cleaner solution but this works so thank you.

Comment: It is not quite simple to detect automatically a dependency chain but maybe you can take a look in Fody https://github.com/Fody/PropertyChanged

Comment: That is great! Thanks for the link!